# Typically, how much could an ferromagnetic core amplify the field of a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

I have been confused by this for days. Consider a ring-shape solenoid with DC current. If we insert a ferromagetic core (cylinder) into the solenoid, how many time it could amplify the field, compared with the case without core?
I understand that the answer would be varied upon materials. However, I have seen dramatically different answer many times. Wikipedia said it would be hundred or thousands of time, while some people and simulation suggest only 2-3 times. That is why I'm asking.

Comment: "while some people and simulation suggest only 2-3 times"  Where did you see that?

Comment: The COMSOL simulation only give 1.5 times amplification using permalloy cores

Comment: Did you compare the H or B magnetic field in the COMSOL calculation?  If the current density on the sides is the same for an infinite length solenoid coil, the H magnetic field will be the same for air and iron cores, and the B magnetic field will be amplified by a factor of $\mu/\mu_0$.

Comment: COMSOL is a program, not an answer. What was put in for $\mu$ in COMSOL to get 1.5?